# How to create Observable that emits items once and then onComplete from BehaviorSubject?

Tags: java, rx-java

I need to create an `Observable<T>` from a `BehaviorSubject<Observable<T>>`. The created observable should only emit items once and then call `onComplete()`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

```
private BehaviorSubject<Observable<T>> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

public Observable<T> getObservable(){
   //return the subject as Observable<T> which emits once and call onComplete()
}
```

Comment: Can you detail them?

Comment: Is the implementation going to change based on the type of BehaviorSubject? OK, let me edit the question.

Comment: I added code to put you on context. Actually I'm implementing a generic abstract class, so there are not types for the BehaviorSubject nor the Observable I need to create (Both are going to be of type T)

Answer (score 3):

So, you have a BehaviorSubject that emits `Observable<T>`s, and from this you want to create an `Observable<T>` that only emits the *first* item of the *first* Observable emitted by the Subject. You could do that like this:

```
public Observable<T> getObservableWithJustOneElement(){
    return subject.flatMap(new Func1<Observable<T>, Observable<T>>(){

        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> source) {
           return source;
        }
    })
    .take(1);
}
```

I know it looks a bit weird but it should be doing what you want. First, the `flatMap` *flattens* the `Observable<Observable<T>>` to just an `Observable<T>` (it just does not do any *mapping* in the sense of transforming the elements). Then, the `take(1)` makes sure that only one item will be emitted with `onNext()` and after that `onCompleted()` will be called.

If you had wanted only the items emitted by the first Observable emitted by the Subject, you could have used this instead:

```
public Observable<T> getObservableWithJustOneElement(){
    return subject.take(1)
    .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<T>, Observable<T>>(){

        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> source) {
           return source;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually, what I meant by "emit items once" is that after the fisrt emission (1 red marble for example... marble diagrams) the Observable product of the BehaviorSubject should complete itself (onComplete()) and stop emitting items.

Comment: So, you have a subject that emits observables and you want to transform that to an observable that only emits the first item of the first observable. Then, take my first solution and append `take(1)` before returning the observable. I will update my solution when I have a keyboard again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an `Observable` that emits once from for example a `ReplaySubject` or a `BehaviourSubject` with [the first operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first).

```
return behaviorSubject.pipe(first());
```

in case you want to return the first item that satisfies certain criteria you can use a predicate as an argument:

```
const predicate = (result: any): boolean => { 
  //your test to check the result should return true...
}
return behaviorSubject.pipe(first(predicate));
```